# Thinking Sphinx geodist search returns locations in a different city

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, thinking-sphinx

I have Thinking Sphinx indexing locations all over the US and I need to find locations closest to a certain lat/lon. In the simplest example, I use the lat/lon of a particular city (lat/lon pulled from Google Maps API) and do a search, sorting by the closest location first.

The problem is, when I search for locations in New York City, it gives me results in Austin, Texas. When I search for location in Austin, I get Jersey Shore, Penn. Each city search gives me results in a completely different city. I'm not even sure where to begin with a problem like this.

Here is my index definition. (The location has an associated city object that also has a lat/lon, hence the location.latitude)

Location:

## Thinking Sphinx

```
define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes :description
    indexes city.name, :as => :city_name

    has "RADIANS(locations.latitude)",  :as => :latitude,  :type => :float
    has "RADIANS(locations.longitude)", :as => :longitude, :type => :float

    set_property :latitude_attr => :latitude, :longitude_attr => :longitude

    # set_property :delta => true
end

###############################################################
```

Without setting the `latitude_attr` property, I kept getting the error:

```
Sphinx Daemon returned error: index location_core: unknown latitude attribute 'latitude'
```

Search command:
`Location.search(:geo => [city.latitude, city.longitude], :order => "@geodist ASC, @relevance DESC", :per_page => 5)`

Any help that can be provided to get me going in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: On a whim, I removed the part that converts the lat/lon from degree to radian and now it works as intended.

[code]has "RADIANS(locations.latitude)",  :as => :latitude,  :type => :float[/code] became [code]has "locations.latitude",  :as => :lat,  :type => :float[/code]

No idea why this works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"RADIANS(locations.latitude)"` converts from degrees, which you are probably using in your database, so you have to convert `:geo => [city.latitude, city.longitude]` to Radians too.
i.e.

```
:geo => Geocoder::Calculations.to_radians([city.latitude, city.longitude])
```

So i think its "working" because both is now degrees OR your database fields were Radians anyway and the convertion was not needed. But docs are saying:

> Keep in mind, though, that Sphinx needs these values to be floats, and
>   tracking positions by radians instead of degrees. If this isn’t the
>   case in your own database (which isn’t a surprise – most people store
>   the values as degrees), then you’ll need to manually convert columns
>   for the attributes:

http://pat.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html

Comment: I did find that to be the solution. The problem actually came this: :geo => [_city.latitude, city.longitude_] I was feeding degree lat/lng to the search, and the index was going off of radian lat/lng. Once I put in a conversion helper, the problem went away.